# Does Magnus spin force affect our Earth?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, projectile, earth

Any spinning moving object experiences a Magnus force. How much does our spinning Earth experience?

Comment: Wouldn't that require Earth moving in a rather thick fluid rather than in a pretty good vacuum?

Comment: @Maxwell I'm guessing you are you making an analogy between fluids and solar particles?

Answer (score 2):

The [Magnus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) occurs when a spinning object is moving through a fluid. It happens because the spin deflects the fluid sideways, so to conserve momentum there is an equal and opposite force on the spinning object.

However the Earth is moving through a vacuum not a fluid. This means there is no Magnus effect force on the Earth.